# How to get sub string before and after space from main string using search in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Below example,

```
import re

OUTPUT = '''
This is sample KLC-SOME345-Sample-VR demo test
'''

search = re.search('( .*Sample-VR)', OUTPUT, re.IGNORECASE)
if search != None:
    print(search.group(1))
```

Result wanted like "**KLC-SOME345-Sample-VR**"

Please help me how to get the exact string. I tried \s and ' ' also but not working

Comment: Does the intended string only contain characters, digits and `-`?

Comment: It contains any special character and alphanumeric. Sample-VR is the fixed one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

OUTPUT = '''This is sample KLC-SOME345-Sample-VR demo test'''

search = re.search(r'([^\s]*Sample-VR[^\s]*)', OUTPUT, re.IGNORECASE)
if search != None:
    print(search.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
KLC-SOME345-Sample-VR
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @Thribhuwan Can you post a string which doesn't function. I suppose you need to use `re.escape()` on your fixed word first

Answer (score 1):

As per the string only contains a-z and 0-9 then you can search for this with `-`

Hope this will help.

```
import re

OUTPUT = '''
This is sample KLC-SOME345-Sample-VR demo test
'''

search = re.search('([0-9a-z-]+Sample-VR)', OUTPUT, re.IGNORECASE)
if search != None:
    print(search.group(1))
```

Output:

```
KLC-SOME345-Sample-VR
```

Comment: This way also can handle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do without `re` just simply split words and search for substring.

```py
OUTPUT = "This is sample KLC-SOME345-Sample-VR demo test"
split_list = OUTPUT.split(" ")
print(split_list)
for value in split_list:
    if "Sample-VR" in value:
        print (value)
```

Output:

```
['This', 'is', 'sample', 'KLC-SOME345-Sample-VR', 'demo', 'test']                                                                                             
KLC-SOME345-Sample-VR
```